# Mailchimp Integration with Segment Capability

Tags: registration, mailchimp

Looking at the available EE plugins handling MailChimp integration there don't appear to be any that automatically allows you to assign subscribers to a "segment".

MailChimp provides Groups and Segments. However there is a hard limit of 60 Groups and I have just over 60 different ways I would like to categorize subscribers. Therefore I am looking to use Segments but none of the plugins seem to provide this option.

My desired functionality is:

- add new **members** to a MailChimp list
- add those members to a MailChimp Segment based on the value from one of the dropdown fields

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can't add MailChimp subscribers to segments - segments are basically just search criteria in MailChimp, based on groups, merge vars, geolocation, etc. So you'd still have to add new members to groups, or set the value of a custom merge variable.

Comment: Hi Derek, it looks like you are correct. I managed to achieve my goal by using merge variables. At first I thought these were simply a way of adding dynamic content to an email e.g. Name but it turns out MailChimp allows you to target subscribers based on the value of the merge variable. Thanks for your help.